# Apache SOLR statistics

Tags: solr, statistics

Is it possible to extract search statistics from Apache SOLR (3.2)? For instance I would like to put in evidence the top terms in a facet field, I have seen the stat component in SOLR but it seems return only numeric values and not specific values for the facet field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stats component in Solr is used to get statistics about values in a certain field (max, min, sum, stddev).

If you want to get the top queried terms you have to handle that at the application level as Solr does not handle that for you.